# Zend Framework : Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: zend-framework, join, zend-db-table

I am getting this error

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Stack trace:
#0 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select), Array)
#3 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1526): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#4 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Db\Table\Abstract.php(1342): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_fetch(Object(Zend_Db_Table_Select))
#5 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\my.localhost\ahaweb\application\models\Tagjoin.php(28): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo))
#6 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\my.localhost\ahaweb\application\models\Tag.php(44): Model_Tagjoin->getTags('12')
#7 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\my.localhost\ahaweb\application\models\Bookmark.php(30): Model_Tag->getTags('12')
#8 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\my.localhost\ahaweb\application\controllers\UserController.php(69): Model_Bookmark->getUserBookmark(1, '12')
#9 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Action.php(513): UserController->editAction()
#10 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('editAction')
#11 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#12 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#13 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\zendframework\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#14 H:\Documents\IIS_Server_Root\my.localhost\ahaweb\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
```

In this code

```
    $tj = new Model_Tagjoin();                
    $stmt = $tj->select('*')->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->joinInner("tags", "tags.tag_id = ".$this->_name.".tag_id",array("tag_name"))
            ->where($this->_name.".bmk_id = ?", $bmk_id)->query();                
    $r = $tj->fetchAll($stmt);
```

When I `print_f` the value of `$stmt` I get

```
SELECT `tagjoins`.*, `tags`.`tag_name` FROM `tagjoins`
INNER JOIN `tags` ON tags.tag_id = tagjoins.tag_id WHERE (tagjoins.bmk_id = '12')
```

which works fine if I use it directly with mysql.

Please help. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Check grants of your Zend db configuration user?

Comment: How to check "grants" of Zend Db Configuration user? I am using mysql root password to connect to mysql.

Comment: run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'hostname';` with the value specified in your Zend db config for user and the hostname from which your application is connecting.

Comment: I got this information: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*196BDEDE2AE4F84CA44C47D54D78478C7E2BD7B7' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: even if I run this code: SELECT `tagjoins`.*, `tags`.`tag_name` FROM `tagjoins`
 INNER JOIN `tags` ON tags.tag_id = tagjoins.tag_id WHERE tagjoins.bmk_id = '12' in zend framework getadapter->query() I get the same error

Comment: Are you **really** using root as your Zend db configured user?  This should be a different user that only has the minimal privileges for what the application needs to do in the database.  Double-check your config.ini and make sure this is not the case.

Comment: this is what I have in application.ini  
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "pass"
resources.db.params.dbname = "my_ahaweb"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

Comment: an strange thing that I found is if I run same query using mysql_query() function. it works perfectly.

Comment: the above query works if I use PDO objects. But using Zend_Db it doesn't work. Please help please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using `printf` but as I have read it in the manual you should use the `assemble()` method to see your final sql query.

something like this.

```
$tj = new Model_Tagjoin();                
$stmt = $tj->select('*')->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->joinInner("tags", "tags.tag_id = ".$this->_name.".tag_id",array("tag_name"))
        ->where($this->_name.".bmk_id = ?", $bmk_id)->query()->assemble();
exit($stmt);                
$r = $tj->fetchAll($stmt);
```

Then try the query in phpMyAdmin and the like.
As a note if this call fails you might wanna remove the `->query()` part of the line.

Comment: assemble() gave me this: SELECT `tagjoins`.*, `tags`.`tag_name` FROM `tagjoins`
 INNER JOIN `tags` ON tags.tag_id = tagjoins.tag_id WHERE (tagjoins.bmk_id = '12')